# How to join two entity table in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, eav, entities

I have created a custom entity table `vaibhav_customtabs_product_entity`, where I have following columns.

```
entity_id
entity_type_id
attribute_set_id
increment_id
store_id
created_at
updated_at
is_active
product_id (entity_id from 'catalog_product_entity')
```

Now my question is how do I join `catalog_product_entity` & `vaibhav_customtabs_product_entity` tables, based on the product entity id. So that, I can fetch the attribute value from my custom entity.
Also from both the entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection(); 

$collection->getSelect()->join(
                        array('cust' => $collection->getTable('vaibhav/customtabs')),
                        'cust.product_id' = 'main_table.entity_id'); 

$this->setCollection($collection); 

parent::_prepareCollection();

return $this;
```

I'm assuming vaibhav/customtabs is you folder structure module_name

Here is a very good reference on how this works with Magento and using a flat and an EAV table. About 1/2 down you will see about 'Validating Your Bind'. In this case, that's your issue. I could write everything in here, but this reference should give you what you looking for. Good Luck and let us know how it turns out!

http://blog.fabian-blechschmidt.de/joining-a-flat-table-on-eav/

Comment: Hi @Anthony this article is about Joining of a flat table with EAV. But I am joining 2 EAV tables. I have gone through the article. It doesn't work out.

Comment: Can I have you skype id so that I can discuss with you directly.

Comment: I've edited the code a little on what I would do. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks, I made some changes and it is working for me now. But the thing is I am not able to add filter here is my code `$collection = Mage::getModel('vaibhav_customtabs/product')->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToSelect(array('title','description'))
   ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', array('eq' => '1'));
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft( array('core'=> 'catalog_product_entity'), 
 'core.entity_id = e.product_id', array('core.sku'));`

Comment: Error `Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend()` when I am adding the filter.  And product_id = entity_id of product

Comment: addFilter('product_id', Value)

Comment: hey @Anthony really I want to thank you man... you made my day :-)

Comment: It's what where here for. Let me know how everything goes with ur project. Sounds like a good one

Answer (score 1):

you can join

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->join(
            array('cust' => 'vaibhav_customtabs_product_entity'),
            'cust.product_id' = 'main_table.entity_id');
```

Comment: Hi @QaisarSatti, I tried the same above code, also I tried to change main_table with catalog_product_entity. But it is giving error.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in  ---- last line @AnthonyCicchelli